# sum of array result as total

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm PHP beginner, I have MySQL query give me array out put like that:

```
0 10.8 0 0 37.2 0 0 106 0 0 0 0 0
```

Code:

```php
$query1 = $this->db->query('SELECT  *, sum(`lines_done`) as 
         sum_lines_done FROM `lines` where id = ' . $id_print . ' ');

$data1= $query1->result();

$tool_all= ($data1[0]->sum_done)
print_r ($tool_all);
```

I want to have total of this array values which equal to 154
how can I do it.

Comment: If you can it's better to do with `SUM` in MySQL, it will perform better.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: it gives me output 0 10.6 0 0 37.4 0 0 106 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 1):

You can SUM using MySQL's function `SUM()`. You can sum an array's values using PHP's function `array_sum` too.

MySQL example:

```
$query = 'SELECT SUM(your_desired_column) AS total FROM your_table';
```

PHP example:

```
$data = [1, 2, 3];
$total = array_sum($data);
echo $total
```

// output: 6

Comment: thanks but it gives me the same output as string I think 0 10.8 0 0 37.2 0 0 106 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: When you print_r or var_dump the array what's showing?

Comment: now after add this code : $tool_all = array($tool_all); $sum = 0; foreach($tool_all as $key=>$value) { $sum+= $value; } print_r ($tool_all); output is like this Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 10.6 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 37.4 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 106 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) but not the sum of the values

Comment: please how can i get the sum ?

Comment: Why are you doing this $tool_all = array($tool_all); ? Is $tool_all an array before doing this or a string?

Comment: one of my trials I suspect that output is string but I was wrong

Comment: If it is an array then just remove that line $tool_all = array($tool_all); and try again. var_dump($tool_all); will let you know what datatype it has.

Comment: var_dump gives me float(0) float(10.6) float(0) float(0) float(37.4) float(0) float(0) float(106) float(0) float(0) float(0) float(0) float(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by below methods

1. Just write a query form SUM Just like

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(your_column) AS Total
FROM
    your_table;
```

2. Get All data sum with for loop

```php
foreach ($data1 as $d) {
     $total = $total+$d;
}
```

Method 2 is a concept polish it and enjoy

Comment: thanks but it gives me the same output as string I think 0 10.8 0 0 37.2 0 0 106 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: now after add this code :

    $tool_all = array($tool_all);
     $sum = 0;
   foreach($tool_all as $key=>$value)
   {
    $sum+= $value;
   }
   print_r ($tool_all);
output is like this Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 10.6 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 37.4 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 106 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) but not the sum of the values

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$tool_all= ($data1[0]->sum_lines_done)
print_r ($tool_all);
```

Explanation:

You have a `lines_done` field, which is a number and you `sum` it into `sum_lines_done`. You used the former, but wanted to use the latter.